# How to align html form inputs and contents spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i align spacing between form inputs, labels, text area and the received data from php. Which may have multiple lines of data to display. How can i achieve the auto arrangement of next elements if something is added in the middle.?

Here is the code: (How can to make auto arrangement? is there a better way achieving it than the below code? )

```css
li{text-decoration:none; list-style-type:none; } 
.left{ position:relative; left:100px;}
.right{ position:relative; left:200px;}
textarea{ position:relative; width:200px; height:70px; }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<br><br>
    
<form>
  <ul>
    <label class="left">Status:</label><li class="right"><textarea name="status"></textarea></li><br><br>
      <label class="left">First name:</label><li class="right"><input type="text" name="firstname"></li><br><br>
     <label class="left">Last name:</label><li class="right"><input type="text"  name="lastname"></li><br><br>
        <label class="left">Address:</label><li class="right"><textarea name="address"></textarea></li><br><br>
        <label class="left">Address 2:</label><li class="right"><textarea  name="address2"></textarea></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Margins? You could set them to something like 5px so they're always below each other

Comment: you have a invalid HTML, `li` elements must be direct child of `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: @Bálint How to apply it for all the form inputs and other contents? I think its a long way to do it...

Comment: why did you use `position:absolute` for the fields .

Comment: @Reddy Updated code with proper format of ul and li still doesn't work.

Comment: @Sudi its still invalid, `li` must be direct children of `ul` or `li ` like `<ul><li></li></ul>` anyways you got your answer below..

Comment: @Sachin forgot about positioning elements (I have read it dint catch it up ) Just googled. It should be relative. Thanks alll....

Comment: @Reddy oh!! do you mean, I shouldn't put any other tags in between..? I have updated my code, could you check if it is a valid format..?

Comment: @Sudi you have to encapsulate all `li`s in one `ul`. Inside each `li` could put what you want then. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve just using `CSS flexbox`.

`display: flex` for each `li`, some `flex-basis` for each `label` (in this case `25%` and add a class for each *input* (such as textarea, etc) with `flex: 1`.

```js
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elem = document.createElement('li');
  elem.innerHTML = '<label>Lorem Ipsum</label><input type="text" class="field" />';
  document.querySelector('#list').appendChild(elem);
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

label {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
  align-self: center;
}

.field {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id=list>
  <li>
    <label for=status>Status:</label>
    <textarea class="field" id=status name="status"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for=firstname>First name:</label>
    <input class="field" id=firstname type="text" name="firstname">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for=lastname>Last name:</label>
    <input class="field" id=lastname type="text" name="lastname">
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for=address>Address:</label>
    <textarea class="field" id="address" name="address"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for=address2>Address 2:</label>
    <textarea class="field" id="address2" name="address2"></textarea>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id=add>Add</button>
```

Also added a `for="..."` attribute to have the right behaviour when click on a `label` (will `focus` on the related `input`).

Comment: Cool. I don't know anything about flex, i'll check on it. Thanks.

Comment: It is super `flex`ible for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I'm stuck with another case. How can i do the same to display retrieved data from database. I mean my code is like this : <!-- <li><label>First name:</label><?php echo $data['First_Name'];?></li> --> The php data breaks to next line...

Comment: what does $data['First_Name'] contains? only a value or also an html tag (like input, etc)? can you control that?

Comment: data from MySQL database, its contains only value. How about encapsulating it with a label tag?

Comment: Didn't `$data['...']` could be the value of the `input`, `textarea`, etc? 
Could you do something like `<li><label for="First_Name">First Name:</label><input class="field" value="<?php echo $data['First_Name'];?>" id="First_Name" /></li>` ?

Comment: I have done that in different page, which lets user to edit their profile. The one I'm asking about now is just to display data. I mean, displaying MySQL data without any input types. Or could i make the textbox invisible..? So that only data inside textbox are showed...

Comment: you could put inside a 'p' with the same class 'field' like <p class="field"><?php echo $data['First_Name'];?></p>

Comment: Thanks!! Last one thing,. I couldn't figure out how to reduce the extended size of the text input.

Comment: you have to control with the flex attribute, take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: great, glad it help you.